# Integrating react application with service fabric - asp.net core

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I have an existing service fabric project and I want to create a new react web application and  host it alongside the ASP.NET Core server-side application. I have read that I can use asp.net core react template project to host both rest API and react from the same sever but I am not sure how to add a react application to an existing REST API hosted by asp.net core.

I was following this article but that only explains about creating a new react using asp.net core react template
https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-core/1525/angular-react-vuejs-svelte-spa-aspnet-core-3